# How can I let my discord bot replies when I say Hi

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I can't let my bot replies to me
I want my bot to say **how are you** whenever someones say **hi**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m', `${bot.user.username} is online on ${bot.guilds.cache.size} servers!`);
});

bot.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.content === 'hi') {
        message.channel.send(`Hi ${message.author}`);
    }
});

bot.login('TOKEN HERE');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`message` event](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message) which is emitted every time a message is sent.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', (message) => {
  console.log(message.content); // this is the content of the message
  if (message.content === 'hi')
    message.channel.send('How are you'); // send a message
});
```

---

I'd recommend reading the [official `discord.js` guide](https://discordjs.guide/) to help you out with questions like this